# Restart current iteration in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to restart the current iteration of the first for loop when `testing12(bad_order, order) == True`. I have tried to use continue but it skips over the iteration which is not what I want.

```
bad_order = []
order = []
for iteration in range(0, 10):

    args = []
    print("\n  def test%d(self):" % (iteration))

    for input in range(num_arguments):

        args.append(pick_type())
        order = args

    if testing12(bad_order, order) == True:
        continue

    try:
        result = target(*args)
        code = test_to_string(target, args, result)

    except Exception as error:
        bad_order = args
        code = test_to_string_exc(target, args, error)
```

Comment: Try changing your design, instead. Either put the meat of the for in a function with some arguments or, according to your requirements, change things completely. I like rewriting code <3

Answer (score 4):

You can add an inner `while` loop which will in effect repeat the outer loop iteration until it exits.  If you can put the repeat condition in the while test, then you're done:

```
for iteration in range(0, 10):
    while some_condition:
        ...
```

If not, you can use a `while True` loop, put an unconditional `break` at the bottom, and use a `continue` to repeat:

```
for iteration in range(0, 10):
    while True:
        ...
        if continue_condition:
            continue
        ...
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also change the:

```
for iteration in range(0,10):
```

to

```
iteration =0 
while iteration < 10 :
```

and increment iteration only when no repeat is needed

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an infinite while loop that breaks at the end of the iteration.

Then you can restart the iteration as often as needed.

```
bad_order = []
order = []
for iteration in range(0, 10):
    while True: #
        args = []
        print("\n  def test%d(self):" % (iteration))

        for input in range(num_arguments):
            args.append(pick_type())
            order = args

        if testing12(bad_order, order) ==  True:
            continue

        try:
            result = target(*args)
            code = test_to_string(target, args, result)
        except Exception as error:
            bad_order = args
            code = test_to_string_exc(target, args, error)

        break #
```